# Why do the knees in my rigify rig bend backwards?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I read about this issue a couple of times but found no explaination what causes this behaviour.

When the feet are in a default position the bend works as expected, but if I put one foot slighty forward I get this:

[image]

First I thought that the bones chain might not have enough angle for the IK solver to determine in wich direction to bend, so I increased the bending of the knees in edit mode but that doesnt help at all. As you can see in the gif, there is also no flipping happening so this cant be the issue.

Can someone explain whats happening here?

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Added a link to the blend file.